# Phonegap based mobile persistent data storage for Android iOS Windows phone

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-build

I am developing a Phonegap based mobile app that will cater to Android + iOS + Windows phones which will have persistent data.

But the problem i see is that different platforms use different APIs (IndexedDB/WebSQL/SQLLite etc.) for storing data and i will have to write different code for all these platforms. Is there a way where this is taken care of and i can write same code that will work for all platforms?

How to do this?

Comment: There are plugings which use the same syntax for all plattforms. Like this: https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Comment: @derdida, Thanks. Is there a Javascript plugin instead of a PhoneGap plugin? That does the same thing? Like a Javascript plugin that checks which kind of database (is it IndexedDB or WebSQL or SQL lite or anything else) is available and applies it behind the code with the developer only needing to write code once.

Answer (score 0):

I use IndexedDB as it's current and WebSQL was deprecated in 2010. IndexedDb is supported on Android and Windows. For iOS devices use the polyfill shim http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/ this will create an abstract layer to convert any indexeddb commands to websql.

Beware that using this shim will have some limitations, I found that creating an index on multiple columns was troublesome so I've avoided that and also using count() on an index range doesn't work so I've had to open a cursor and loop through instead.

Comment: Thanks. Since, I was not getting and replies for somtime, and after looking out for various JS libraries that are available, I found and started implementing [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) in my app. Because, it has built-in support for various data formats like IndexedDB, webSQL, gears-SQL, etc... I'm still not in a stage to confirm the results. But once I find out, I will reply back. Meanwhile, I will also check your solution. Thanks again :)